# Is it possible to use Angular AutGuard on checking for not only pages but also records?

Tags: angular, authentication, guard

In our angular project, we use page based authentication by using Auth Guard with respect to users ROLES.

In addition, our records have Read, Write and Admin permissions also.

Is it possible to use Auth Guard to control authentication on records for read, write and admin permissions?

Regards

Comment: You can also try [ngx-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions)  library to control permissions in your applications. It removes objects from DOM and dont hides them via css (also have support for lazy loading).

Answer (score 2):

Not really. There are few routing guards but all of them only deal with page loading.

FYI, full list of guards: `CanActivate`, `CanActivateChild`, `CanDeactivate`, `Resolve` and `CanLoad`. The names quite clearly defines what they do.

To restrict users to perform specific actions you will have to make something on your own. For example, you could create directive to display "Edit" button only for specific role, etc.

Also keep in mind that implementing security in UI should be pure cosmetic and actual security should be implemented on the back-end.